# Is an identical recreation of our world's creation happening right now?

Tags: alternate-history, alternate-worlds, universe, alternate-reality

If we assume the scientific idea of parallel universes, assuming that all universes that exist now are different from each other in the present and/or past, and so a new universe is created every time there can be a change in two, acting as one, universe(s). Then is there a world identical to our own, but for 1 difference, being created now?

And if so is there a world in which that 1 difference doesn't actually affect the creation of the earth, thus being a recreation of our world's creation is happening right now?

And if so is our world just a recreation of another world, meaning that our so called "history" at some point was actually just the history or a world identical to ours before some change?

Comment: Hi, the Philosophical, welcome to Worldbuilding Stack Exchange. Can you explain a little how this question relates to worldbuilding? Thanks.

Comment: Interesting question but it doesn't seem like answerable question based on the SE format.  If you have questions on writing good questions and answers feel free to ask and check out the [help]

Comment: I am possibly not completely aware of the parameters of Worldbuilding. Thanks for the advice about the help centre, I will have a look.

Comment: How odd, one person has favourited the question  but not up-voted it.

Answer (score 1):

The scientific version of the idea you put forth is known as the Many Worlds Interpretation of quantum mechanics.  It is not a scientific theory, but merely an interpretation.  It is a valid interpretation of the mathematics which does not contradict the reality we observe in any noticeable way.  It's also slightly more nuanced, in that it deals with superpositions of worlds.

The mathematical version of this would require us to specify how many worlds there are and how many states there could be.  It would also point out that there is no obligation of these universes being distributed uniformly.  We may be an outlier, such that no world is quite like ours, or there may be infinitely many "clones" of our world.

The philosophical version would question what it means for a world to be identical to our own but for 1 change in the first place.  Many philosophers would argue that "you" or "I" are unique, and thus any world with only one difference would suggest that you or I must not exist!

Applied mathematicians would suggest the question you are asking is with regard to the path invariance of our world.  Does it matter how we got here, or only that we got here.  Computer scientists might even bring up the concept of memorization to suggest how to implement a path invariant world time evolution efficiently.

So there's not just one way to look at this problem.  Everyone will look at it a slightly different way.  You get to decide where that leads you.

Comment: I can see what Cort Ammon means in his answer, however would say that as each universe is separate, and unknown to any other world, does the location or organisation of the worlds matter. I am also talking about everything in a purely material sense, making "you" or "I" only a collection of atoms (I apologise if it wasn't clear about that). This is my first question not to be accused of duplication!

Comment: If the universes are separate, then the next question is how many are there.  The number of universes cannot be inferred from what we have here.  As an example of the direction that leads, the next question we have is what is a "change."  If there are countably infinite changes, then the most likely answer is that there are no universes like ours because the state-space for our universe by current theories is uncountably infinite.

Comment: It has been suggested that the worlds can differ by a single quantum state. So to accommodate all possible quantum states in all possible configurations, 10^1000 worlds are 'created' every second. The 'closest' worlds to our own in such a state-space will be effectively indistinguishable for ours.